# Why does mediaDevices.enumerateDevices list some devices twice? What is default?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I write this code in JavaScript in Chrome:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
  .then((list) => {
    console.log(list);
  });
```

This outputs a list of media devices like microphones and cameras. Each device is represented as an object with its own `deviceId`. But some devices, like one of the microphones in particular, are listed twice. And one time their respective `deviceId` is set to `'default'`. What is so special about a one default microphone? And how do I tell which actual `deviceId` it has?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `deviceId` lets web sites manage which device their user is using. E.g. store it in a cookie to remember the user's preference from last time.

Some browsers (Chrome, Opera) list the same microphone twice, with different ids. In my case:

1. Default - Internal Microphone (Built-in)
2. Internal Microphone (Built-in)

The former is "the OS default", whatever the end-user has configured in *System Preferences/Sound* (OSX) or *Control Panel/Sound* (Windows). The idea is: when recalled from a cookie and used, its id gets you whatever is configured in the OS *at the time of use*, which may differ from last time.

The latter is always the specific mic. Their `groupId`s match; they're the same physical device atm.

The `deviceId = "default"` is an oddity of Chrome (and Opera). AFAICT it's a valid id like any other. If you want the other one, compare their `groupId`s to find it.

Safari does not do this. Firefox recently stopped doing it (as of version 63).

Cameras are never duplicated in this way.

Comment: When I tried the same method in my project using (sip.js for audio call), it shows same device 3 times with different deviceID:
1. Default
2. Communications
3. some_actual_long_id

What does communication device ID mean here ?

Comment: @NaveenKumar That's a virtual [Windows thing](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/set-default-microphone-windows-10/) I think.